# Composer loading from cache

Tags: php, composer-php

I ran into a problem using composer for installing/uninstalling some dependencies in laravel, which come back after deleting them from `composer.json` and deleting their vendor folder.

I initially used dflydev's markdown package, but now I want to change it to michelf's php-markdown, but I can't uninstall the old one since it comes back loaded from cache. I checked at `AppData\Roaming\Composer` and it is empty.

Any clue as to why this is happening?

```
  - Installing dflydev/markdown (dev-master dee1f7a)
    Loading from cache
```

Comment: Have you tried anything to resolve this problem? If yes, please share your attempts

Comment: I tried adding --no-cache option to my composer command and it downloaded the dependencies without loading them from cache....

Answer (score 208, accepted):

You can use the following command to clear the cache irrespective of the OS you are on:

```
php composer.phar clear-cache
```

or if composer is installed globally

```
composer clear-cache
```

Comment: Unless I deleted my `composer.lock` file, the `clear-cache` commands had no effect.

Comment: Remember that it must be executed with root(super user).

Comment: Please add some further explanation to your answer. How does clearing the cache of downloaded files help to install or not install any pacakge?

Answer (score 53):

I think, you can run your `composer` commands with `--no-cache` option flag like

```sh
composer install --no-cache
```

Or

```sh
composer require <package-name> --no-cache
```

Or

```sh
composer update [<package-name>] --no-cache
```

Answer (score 20):

If you want to clear all packages cache, please try following:

```
$ composer clearcache
```

<strike>Or to just clear one or a few packages:</strike>

```
$ composer clearcache packagename1 packagename2 ...
```

You can also use `clear-cache` which is an alias for `clearcache`.

Source : https://blog.liplex.de/clear-composer-cache/

Comment: It's not possible anymore to clear cache for specific packages. There is a comment in the post you've referenced and the post itself was updated.

Comment: Please add some further explanation to your answer. How does clearing the cache of downloaded files help to install or not install any pacakge?

Answer (score 19):

composer caches packages under vendor/packagename convention. So you shouldn't run into any issue, just because the packagename is used in another vendor's package.

the cache locations are:

- **Windows**: %LOCALAPPDATA%\Composer\files\vendor\packagename
- **Linux**: ~/.composer/cache/files/vendor/packagename
- **macOS**:  ~/Library/Caches/composer/files/packagename

Comment: under windows its %LOCALAPPDATA%\Roaming\Composer and its as i said empty, and the package in question isn't used in any dependency as a i just installed it recently.

Comment: Please add some further explanation to your answer. How does clearing the cache of downloaded files help to install or not install any pacakge?

Comment: UPDATE 2022: for OSX:  ~/Library/Caches/composer/

Comment: This will work on any platform and give you the exact location: `composer config cache-dir`

Answer (score 10):

Don't edit your `composer.json` file manually to remove a package - it will remain in `composer.lock`.

Use `composer remove` to delete the old package then `composer require` to install the replacement.

Comment: This looks like the first attempt to really solve the problem - thanks for your answer!

Comment: Yeah... We should probably change the question title, it's a bit misleading

Comment: This doesn't work if the package has been installed via dependency. There are reasons why you might need to manually edit composer.json ie if you want to update a reference to use a local path for a package.

Comment: > This doesn't work if the package has been installed via dependency.

Correct. But the OP states directly that they are deleting the items from `composer.json` and they are magically returning

> There are reasons why you might need to manually edit composer.json

Absolutely. Again, not applicable in this context, where the OP is trying to remove a whole package. I *could* have said "run `composer update` after deleting the value" but that comes with *so* much more required knowledge.

Answer (score 7):

In some cases (for example OpenSuse 42.1) all user cache are puts in:

```
~/.cache/
```

For the composer, the same as other applications, the cache path is:

```
~/.cache/composer/
```

So, just remove this folder as follow:

```
rm -fR ~/.cache/composer
```

Comment: Please add some further explanation to your answer. How does clearing the cache of downloaded files help to install or not install any pacakge?

Answer (score 4):

run the following command

```
rm -rf ~/.composer/cache*
```

if Permission denied add sudo

Comment: If some one is having permissions issues in their own home directory, "add sudo" to a `rm -rf` command that includes a wildcard is not a good idea.

Comment: Please add some further explanation to your answer. How does clearing the cache of downloaded files help to install or not install any pacakge?

Answer (score 2):

On **Window**, I see the composer cache file located in
`C:\Users\{your_user}\AppData\Local\Composer\files`

[image]

It stores ZIP files. The below image has 2 Zip files because I have downloaded 2 versions of monolog (1.0.1 and 1.0.2)
[image]

To remove the cache, simply delete the Zip file or folder.

Comment: This will work on any platform and give you the exact location: `composer config cache-dir`

Answer (score -1):

So the only thing that worked for me on my Macbook was removing the package from my `composer.json`, deleting my `composer.lock`, running `composer update`, then adding the package back to `composer.json`, deleting my `composer.lock`(again), and running `composer update` (again). I had a local package in my instance of Laravel Nova that I changed to all lowercase from CamelCase and no matter what I did, it kept adding the package with the old CamelCase name. Didn't matter if I cleared caches or anything.