# Symfony Process error when running composer Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

suddenly in my project with laravel 8 I ran composer to uninstall a dependency that I want to reinstall for a sense nothing more than order and start from scratch and I started to throw this error that has to do with Symfony Process:

PHP Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: fclose (): Argument # 1 ($ stream) must be of type resource, bool given in phar: // C: /ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/process/ Pipes / WindowsPipes.php: 71

What can be the mistake? I read something like that has to do with the update of the symfony Process but I don't know why. The only thing I did was install Laravel / Passport for the use of token in the user login.

Comment: Did you get the error when you ran `composer install`?

Comment: I got this error after a composer install failed. 
Then all composer commands everywhere failed. I even tried a new .phar and they still failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whilst running PHP 8 on Windows I too had this error. I tried to clear out the temp directory manually per [Composer loading from cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22700728/composer-loading-from-cache) - when that didn't work. I also found that composer's symfony usage had *locked* a temp file in an odd way.

I needed to clear the temp file, and I used filelocker to unlock it, easily enough. Once I had unlocked and deleted the file, I was able to run composer as expected again.

Here is a related stack overflow question about the temp file location: [Composer install: error on temporary file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34741530/composer-install-error-on-temporary-file) (%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp works for me)

They have names like 'sf_proc_00.err'. I found them easily by sorting the temp files by date, and only trying to remove the ones modified today.

A reboot, or identifying the symfony process tying up the temp file would also work.  According to file locked - it was an instance of mingw git for me.